# Como executar procedures dentro de outra?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Possuo essa procedure onde eu salvo dentro de um cursor todas as outras procedures que precisam ser executadas, depois eu percorro o cursor colocando os nomes das procedures dentro de uma variável.

Como fazer para executar essas procedures que estão com o nome dentro da variável+?

```
CURSOR cur_procedures IS
SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME like  
'%P_CES_INTERF_DIMOF_TREE_%' and OBJECT_TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE') 
and OBJECT_NAME not like '%P_CES_INTERF_DIMOF_TREE_SPS%'
order by OBJECT_NAME; 

Proc varchar(50);


BEGIN

OPEN cur_procedures;
LOOP 
FETCH cur_procedures INTO Proc;
EXIT WHEN cur_procedures%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_procedures;


END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o comando [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)